# AngularJS How do I pre select the value of a dropdown when the value is retrieved from a webservice?

Tags: angularjs

Hello community been stuck on this one for a while...

**Scenario:** 
I have a dropdownlist which I pre-populate with values fetched from a service.
Now that same object returned from the service lets me know the value that needs to be pre-selected for that dropdownlist. The service returns a JSON object with all this information.

Sample JSON Returned from service

```
{
    "stepsInvolved": [{
        "label": "Step 1",
        "value": "Step 1"
    }, {
        "label": "Step 1",
        "value": "Step 1"
    }, {
        "label": "Step 1",
        "value": "Step 1"
    }],
    "valueSelected": {
        "label": "Step 1",
        "value": "Step 1"
    }
}
```

Question

Using Angular I'm assigning the dropdown list values from `stepsInvolved` into a scope variable `$scope.options` thats pretty straight forward.

*How do I preselect the value on the dropdownlist with the value indicated in the "valueSelected" from the JSON object? How do you accomplish this with angular?*

JSFiddles and Plunkers are welcome.

P.S : Obviously this doesn't work for this scenario

```
$scope.options= stepsInvolved;
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give value to your model in select tag

In your controller asign

```
$scope.selectedValue = 'Step 1';  //your selected value, assign it in any way you wish
$scope.stepsInvolved = response['stepsInvolved'];
```

I am assuming your object is assigned to "response"

```
<select ng-model='selectedValue' ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in stepsInvolved"></select>
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks bro a true legend you are... I was missing the "as item.label" in ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in stepsInvolved" Thanks heaps...

Answer (score 2):

[ngSelected](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) is the directive of choice: http://plnkr.co/edit/dGJWityhYUZd9Ht6VgSJ?p=preview