# How to show the selected value from the list in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selecteditem

I am new to Angular.Js. If I hava a dropdown and and it is picking the selected data from the dropdown. I am able to do that but It is not bringing the selected value for that dropdown. What is the property I need to set so whenever I come to that page, it shows the selected value in the dropdown .

Here is a portion of my code:

```
 <select class='form-control' id="CreateRouteType"
  ng-options="createRoute.Name for createRoute in   vm.CreateRouteList"
 ng-model="vm.ProcessDataSettings.CreateRouteTypeId" >
 <option value="vm.ProcessDataSettings.CreateRouteTypeId" selected></option>
                        </select>
```

what do I need to do to show the selected value in the dropdown as selected?

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I am wrong. Are you asking when you change options, what is the value in the memory?

Looks like you have ng-model="vm.ProcessDataSettings.CreateRouteTypeId". I am sure the selected value is in the vm.ProcessDataSettings.CreateRouteTypeId ?

Comment: So when I select a value from the CreateRouteList, It is selected but when I save it it is not selected anymore, Where is database I have the selected value store, so my question is basically how do you bring back the selectedvalue to the dropdown in Angular?

Comment: I see your question now.  You are asking where the state had been saved.  Actually in Javascript, everything is not saved. You need to either move them into some storage solution such as localstorage, cookies, or even a database.  Retrieve it again when your app (page) is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [AngularJS How do I pre select the value of a dropdown when the value is retrieved from a webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601717/angularjs-how-do-i-pre-select-the-value-of-a-dropdown-when-the-value-is-retrieve)

```
<select class='form-control' id="CreateRouteType"
ng-options="createRoute.Name for createRoute in   vm.CreateRouteList"
 ng-model="vm.ProcessDataSettings.CreateRouteTypeId" >
                        </select>
```

essentially, in your controller initialize function, you should set the value of ng-model in the select tag to what you want to be preselected. So something like this:

$scope.vm.ProcessDataSettings.CreateRouteTypeId = the object that you want to be preselected;